# login_required django decorator

Tags: python, django

I wanted to use `login_required` with function based views.I gone through [Django's official docs of django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required). I could not grab it clearly.

Issue is , the control is returning back to `login` function even though user is already authenticated instead of going to home page. 
What else changes are required to allow login using my code?

```
def login(request):
    """
    """
    data_dict = {}
    if request.POST:
        req_dict = dict(zip(request.POST.keys(), request.POST.values()))
        accmgr = AccountManager()
        user = accmgr.validate_user(**req_dict) 
        if user:
            ret = redirect('homepage')
        else:
            data_dict["msg"] = "Username  or password is incorrect!"
            ret =  render(request, "login.html", data_dict)
    else:
        ret =  render(request, "login.html", data_dict)
    return ret

@login_required(login_url='/login')
def homepage(request):
    '''
    '''
    return render(request, "adminpage.html", {"title":"Hello World"})
```

**NOTE** : `accmgr.validate_user` internally checks `user.is_authenticated`.There are some other checks I had to do to allow user so added custom function.

Also added `LOGIN_URL` in settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL ='/login/'
```

Comment: `login_required` decorator checks `request.user`. Probably `accmgr.validate_user` method does not really authenticate the user. You should call [`authenticate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) instead, to actually log user in.

Comment: @ozgur -  thanks! Now I updated code to use `authenticate` but still the issue persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`login_required` decorator checks if `request.user.is_authenticated()` returns `True`. Probably the issue is, `accmgr.validate_user` method does not really authenticate the user.

You should call [`authenticate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.authenticate) instead, to actually log user in.

```
from django.contrib.auth import login as django_login
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate

def login(request):
    ...
    req_dict = request.POST.copy()
    user = authenticate(
        username=req_dict['username'], password=req_dict['password'])

    if user:
        django_login(request, user)
    ...
```

Please see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/auth/default/#how-to-log-a-user-in) for more information.

Comment: Let me check! I'm not using `django_login`.
`+1 for req_dict = request.POST.copy()`

Comment: You have to use `django_login` to actually log user in. The built-in function attaches `user` object to `request` instance so `login_required` works as expected.